# replace subquery mySQL with Join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am building a web-based chatting system (mysql, php, jquery), listed by conversations, where each conversation shows the last message sent only. (like fb).

the table has the next fields, where `conversation_code` is a unique token, shared by all the messages whitin the conversation.

```
id_message, id_sender, id_receiver, conversation_code, message_date,
```

I am currently working with this SQL query:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_messages 
 WHERE message_date IN (SELECT max(message_date) 
 FROM table_messages WHERE  id_sender='$id_session' OR  id_receiver='$id_session'   
 GROUP BY conversation_code) 
 ORDER BY message_date DESC
```

This query,returns results as expected but delays too much to load (ajax). I was told that this delay is because the using of subqueries. Is there any other way to replace the subquery for `JOIN` or something else in order to avoid the delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on an inner join (dinamic) instead of in

```
SELECT a.* FROM table_messages as a
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT max(message_date) as md
          FROM table_messages 
          WHERE  id_sender='$id_session' OR  id_receiver='$id_session'   
          GROUP BY  conversation_code) t on t.md = a.message_date  
 ORDER BY a.message_date DESC
```

Comment: Lol, my friend you are a genius, thanks you, it worked! the speed returned to the page.